# Problem with anonymous login to mozilla cvs

Tags: cvs, mozilla

I have an existing Bugzilla installation that I'm trying to upgrade via CVS as per the instructions found here:  http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.4/en/html/upgrade.html#upgrade-cvs.

Basically, I just need to login to the mozilla cvs server, but when I try to do so, it won't accept the 'anonymous' password (or a blank one).  I just get dumped back to the bash shell.

I try to login as follows:

```
cvs login
```

and get the response:

```
Logging in to :pserver:anonymous@cvs-mirror.mozilla.org:2401/cvsroot
CVS password:
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just get dumped back to the bash shell.

That's what supposed to happen. Now do a `cvs update` with the flags you need.